# Creating a system using OCR & vb.net

Tags: vb.net, system, ocr

My groupmates and I are planning to make a Parking System for a university using OCR & VB.net

Before a car parks, a webcam will capture and read the plate number and will go to a process through vb.net that records the plate number.

Is that possible?

Comment: Oh... license plate recognition is so simple now? It's a research project in my years! Your "OCR" may not be fast enough in pure VB.Net but you may try OpenVC (Emgu VC for .Net) to help you a bit on the image processing part.

Comment: So that's what it's called. Any idea on how to get it started, sir? Actually, vb.net isn't my forte but this is what our panelists gave us for our capstone project.

Comment: Interesting project.  I have done this task some years ago with marginal success.  When is your completed project due?

Comment: On December, Probably. But for August to the 2nd week of October our group should focus on the documentation for this research project. Then by the 3rd week of October until February we should focus in doing the said system. But our group can also start making the system now for us to finish on time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [.Net wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract) for tesseract-ocr to recognize your images.